# Base class undefined

Tags: c++, class, undefined, radix

I know it is one of the constant ask question
so i get this error

'WorldObject': [Base class undefined (translated from german)]

Here is the code which produce this error:

### **ProjectilObject.h:**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef _PROJECTILOBJECT_H_
#define _PROJECTILOBJECT_H_

#include "GameObjects.h"

class ProjectilObject: public WorldObject
{
public:
    ProjectilObject(IGameObject* parent,int projectiltype);

    void deleteyourself();
protected:
virtual void VProcEvent( long hashvalue,    std::stringstream &stream);
    virtual void VInit();
    virtual void VInitfromStream( std::stringstream &stream     );
    virtual void VonUpdate();
    virtual void VonRender();
private:
    vec3 vel;

    float lifetime;
    float lifetimeend;

    vec3 target;

    int m_projectiltype;
};

#endif
```

Here is the code file from the WorldObject class:

### **GameObjects.h:**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef _GAMEONJECTCODE_H_
#define _GAMEONJECTCODE_H_

#include "IGameObject.h"
#include "Sprite.h"
#include "GamePath.h"
#include "HashedString/String.h"
#include "IAttribute.h"
#include "CharacterObjects.h"
#include "ProjectilObject.h"
```

**[...]**

```
class WorldObject: public IGameObject, public MRenderAble
{
public:
    WorldObject(IGameObject* parent);
    virtual bool IsDestroyAble();
    virtual bool IsMageAble();
    virtual bool IsRenderAble();
protected:
    virtual void VProcEvent( long hashvalue, std::stringstream &stream);
    virtual void VonUpdate();
    virtual void VonRender();
    virtual void VInit() =0;
    virtual void VInitfromStream( std::stringstream &stream ) =0;
    virtual void VSerialize( std::stringstream &stream );

    vec3 poscam;    
};
```

**[...]**

```
#endif
```

There are some other Classes in this file but they shouldn't interrupt, I think.
Maybe there is a tiny error I didn't saw but I don't understand why this error is produced. When you need more of the code feel free to ask because i think it would only disturb.

Comment: Did you mean `MRenderable` instead of `MRenderAble`? Also, you've got circular dependencies going on there between the two files. You need a forward declaration instead.

Comment: @chris 
Same error with and without a forward declaration.
`MRenderable` and `MRenderAble` has nothing to do with the problem. I think. `MRenderAble` is another class I created in the file "IAttribute.h".

Comment: Well, you need to include a full class in order to inherit it, so a forward declaration is useless there, but in your `GameObjects.h`, a forward declaration of `ProjectilObject.h` would probably suffice.

Comment: You can only inherit from a *complete* type.

Comment: @JimRaid, Did you edit your code to fix mistakes??? gztomas had a correct answer according to your original post but you removed the broken code on May 20 at 17:37, while gztomas was working on his answer. Don't do that! We must be able to see the error in order to understand the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have any source file that includes `GameObjects.h` before `ProjectilObject.h` or does not include `ProjectilObject.h` directly, then the compiler will first find the declaration of `ProjectilObject` through the include in `GameObjects.h` before knowing what `WorldObject` is. That is because `GameObjects.h` first includes `ProjectilObject.h` and then declares `WorldObject`. In that case the include of `GameObjects.h` present in `ProjectilObject.h` won't work because `_GAMEONJECTCODE_H_` will be already defined.

To avoid this, either be sure to include `ProjectilObject.h` instead of `GameObjects.h` in your source file, or use [forward declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration).

Comment: The link on forward declarations specifically states that you cannot use it to define a base class

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to answer this question without looking at the whole code. Even a misplaced brace could count. Check your namespaces - are you sure the WorldObject is in the same namespace?

I suggest you use the #pragma message by placing it near the WorldObject definition and checking the compiler output:

> #pragma message ("World object is defined")

If it does not show up, move the pragma to the parent .h file and check the compiler output again. With this you can easily locate the error.

Comment: Namespace - This was the underlying problem to my Base class undefined error.  Once I determined that I did not have circular dependency, I saw that the base class in question was not qualified by the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

```
class WorldObject;
class ProjectilObject: public WorldObject
```

You are forward declaring WorldObject, but to inherit from a class you need the definition, so you have to include the header of WorldObject.

Answer (score 0):

In my case: i delete derived class include from  base class header file.

for example:

file 1 :
#include "B.h"

-> A()

file 2:

-> B() : A()

solution : delete #include "B.h" from file1